# Cannot publish web service - Error : Could not open Source file: The given path's format is not supported

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2013

We are trying to publish a web service from our Dev box onto the UAT box.

There are no errors when building the web-service, but when trying to publish (using UNC path: `\\TEST-SERVER\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PerformanceReviewWebService`) we get the below error message and the process fails:

```
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(1475,5): 
Error : Could not open Source file: The given path's format is not supported.
```

what can we do to track down this error and resolve it?

On the target box we have checked the security of the folder:

```
..\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PerformanceReviewWebService
```

and we definitely have access to write into that directory.

We have no build errors.

Comment: maybe the $ sign in your path makes sort of problem with security issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things you can try that may help debug or resolve the issue:

1. Try launching Visual Studio as an Administrator and retry publishing.
2. Try publishing to a local location. Does this succeed?
   If yes there is likely a problem with either accessing the UNC path or a file/security permission issue
3. If local publishing does not succeed, make sure you haven't mistakenly moved any of you bin, contents or webconfig files to a different location.
4. Check for files in Visual Studio that are light grey, or have an exclamation mark next to them (They may be missing from the project).
   Attempt to possibly reload the project to a prior state where publishing was successful. Continue making updates gradually until your project is up to date.
5. Create a new empty project and attempt to publish to the same location. If this works you have something corrupted or wrong in you existing project. You can try excluding files or folders from the build to narrow down which ones may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case a referenced web-project shared content with the web-project I want to publish. After removing it from the content of the referenced project it was working again.